# LINQ ToList() throws error on async method

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asynchronous, async-await

I have the following method:

```
protected override async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAll(QueryData query)
{
     IEnumerable<Entity> entities = await _entityManager.UseRepositoryAsync(async (repo) =>
     {
          var fetchExpression = FetchExpression(query);
          IEnumerable<Entity> found = await (fetchExpression != null ?
                                      repo.BrowseAllAsync(fetchExpression) :
                                      repo.BrowseAllAsync());
          return found;
     });
     return Ok(entities.Select(e => MapToDTO(e));
}
```

This function compiles fine.

However, if I proceed to add a `ToList()` at the end, it throws an error:

> Since `System.Func<XXX.Framework.Persistence.IAsyncRepository<Entity>,System.Threading.Tasks.Task>` is an async method that returns `Task`, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression.
>
> Did you intend to return `Task<T>`?

```
protected override async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAll(QueryData query)
{
     IEnumerable<Entity> entities = await _entityManager.UseRepositoryAsync(async (repo) =>
     {
          var fetchExpression = FetchExpression(query);
          IEnumerable<Entity> found = await (fetchExpression != null ?
                                      repo.BrowseAllAsync(fetchExpression) :
                                      repo.BrowseAllAsync());
          return found.ToList(); //THROWS ERROR
     });
     return Ok(entities.Select(e => MapToDTO(e));
}
```

I'm failing to understand the error message. What's going on?

**Note**: `UseRepositoryAsync` is an overloaded method and has the following sintax:

```
Task<R> UseRepositoryAsync(Func<IAsyncRepository<E>, Task<R>> operation);
Task UseRepositoryAsync(Func<IAsyncRepository<E>, Task> operation);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your method signature says:

```
Task<R> UseRepositoryAsync(Func<IAsyncRepository<E>, Task<R>> operation);
```

But, the `Task` returned is actually an `Task<IEnumerable<R>>` (where R is `Entity`), since you return a collection and not a single item. Since your methods best overload is currently a `Task`, and you're using `async-await`, the compiler yells when you try to return anything from the lambda.

Change the overload to receive and return a collection:

```
Task<IEnumerable<R>> UseRepositoryAsync(Func<IAsyncRepository<E>, Task<IEnumerable<R>> operation);
```